# How to match values from a data frame to values in a list and then append the list in R?

Tags: r

Hope the title isn't too confusing. But what im trying to do is match values associated with a variable name (from a data frame) to variables in a data frame inside a list... and then append the list with the matched values.

For example, if I have a data frame that contains 2 columns, i.e., the variable name and values, like so:

```
# create a dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  variable = paste0("x", 1:10),
  value = sample(1:20, 10, replace = T)
)
df
> df
   variable value
1        x1     2
2        x2     8
3        x3     5
4        x4    11
5        x5     1
6        x6    13
7        x7    16
8        x8     8
9        x9    20
10      x10    13
```

and then if I have another data frame inside a list like:

```
# create a list
myList <- list(
  newDf = data.frame(
    var = c("x1", NA, NA, "x5", "x4", NA, "x3")
  )
)
```

What im trying to do is to match the value for a variable from `df` to the variables in `newDf` in my list and then add the value to the corresponding variable in `newDf`. For clarity, my expected result for the above example would look like:

```
$newDf
   var value
1   x1     2
2 <NA>    NA
3 <NA>    NA
4   x5     1
5   x4    11
6 <NA>    NA
7   x3     5
```

So, we can see from `df` the value for `x1` is 2, and since `x1` is in `newDf` we add that value to the list, the value for `x5` is 1, so we add it to the list, etc

Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `match` -

```
lapply(myList, function(x) transform(x,value = df$value[match(var,df$variable)]))

#$newDf
#   var value
#1   x1     2
#2 <NA>    NA
#3 <NA>    NA
#4   x5     1
#5   x4    11
#6 <NA>    NA
#7   x3     5
```

Or `merge` -

```
lapply(myList, function(x) merge(x, df, by.x = 'var', by.y = 'variable', all.x = TRUE))
```

If the `length(myList)` is always 1 you may skip `lapply` and perform this operation directly on `myList[[1]]`.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer to the question. First the data.frame is stringsAsFactors=FALSE. Then we may find by the index of df which is the same as the list.

```
df <- data.frame(
  variable = paste0("x", 1:10),
  value = c(2, 8, 5, 11, 1, 13, 16, 8, 20, 13), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

myList <- list(
  newDf = data.frame(
    var = c("x1", NA, NA, "x5", "x4", NA, "x3"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
)


s=lapply( 1:7, function(x) df[which(  myList[['newDf']][x,]==df[, 'variable']), ]  )
do.call(rbind.data.frame, s)
```